# Who said that? Can the IFTTT Google Assistant service capture which device the request came from and pass it on?

Tags: google-home, ifttt, google-assist-api

Most of my home automation is controlled internally (timers, events, scenes, etc).  I also have voice control (mainly just for fun).  I have some google home devices scattered throughout the house with a few IFTTT phrases like "Open the blinds in the $ (e.g. lounge room)".  When that phrase is triggered, WebHooks POSTs a request to my home server to open the blinds.

Anyway it would be nice if I could just say "Open the blinds" and the room would be implied by which Google Home device processed the phrase.  That doesn't seem possible with the IFTTT services.  It actually seems like a glaring oversight, so maybe I'm missing something.

Any ideas on how I could implement this seemingly simple feature? (I'm hoping I won't have to query the Google Assistant myself).

Answer (score 0):

I think I have enough information now to answer my own question.  The 'IFTTT Platform' seems to be the key to all my requirements.  It will give me greater access to the Google Assistant API (magnitudes greater than the IFTTT GUI).  However, it's a steep learning curve:

Step 1: Learn the Ruby programming language

Step 2: Umm I'll get back to you on the next steps :)